# Synchronizing on a Thread Object

Tags: java, multithreading, scjp

From [Niko's java blog](http://nikojava.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/scjp-mock-exam-for-threads/)

> These classes are defined in the same file. What is the output? (1
>   correct answer)

```
class Job extends Thread {
    private Integer number = 0;
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            number++;
        }
    }
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws InterruptedException {
        Job thread = new Job();
        thread.start();
        synchronized (thread) {
            thread.wait();
        }
        System.out.println(thread.getNumber());
    }
}
```

> - It prints 0.
> - It prints 999999.
> - The output is not guaranteed to be any of the above.

The output is `999999`. I understand that when a Thread completes its `run()` method, it terminates and with it, all the locks the Thread had get released. However, in this exercise, it's used the Thread object as a lock, should not it be considered as a normal object? I mean the lock it's not owned by the Thread `thread` but by the main Thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code relies on an implementation detail that was not documented before Java 7, and now is (in the [documentation of the `join()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long,%20int%29)), but with the following words:

> As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

So I don't know where this question was asked, but it really tests if you know the hidden corner-cases of threading, that you should never use in any sane program.

Comment: Note that the thread may have completed before `main` acquires the lock. / What's important is you use private lock objects instead of doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes. And due to spurious wakeups, the wait call could return before the job has completed, so I would check the answer: The output is not guaranteed to be any of the above.

Comment: @JBNizet However the join() method is not used in the snippet. We can get only some theoretical implication that that approach is used also when a thread dies?

Comment: @Rollerball It's certainly a peculiar piece of documentation, because it's the implementation of the code that handles `Thread.run` which is significant and that is only indirectly documented.

Comment: @Rollerball: This documentation tells how join works, but since it's implemented by waiting on the thread, which calls notifyAll(), it will also wake up any thread waiting on the ending thread.